# Why is the images overwriting?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm learning Javascript and Canvas. Help me someone please in such situation. I want to draw a lines of images in few colons, the last is always overwriting the previous.

Here is the example:

```
  function main(){
     contains Canvas creating
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = WIDTH;
    canvas.height = HEIGHT;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

     and init();
    }
```

// Row is the my constructor with coordinates and drawImage method. DrawImage accept the array of images;

```
function Row(x,y){
            var _this = this;
            _this.x = x;
            _this.y = y;

            this.drawImage = function(img2){

                img.onload = function(){
                    for(var i = 0; i < img2.length; i+=1){
                    ctx.drawImage(img2[i], _this.x, this.y + i * canvas.height / 4, canvas.width / 5, canvas.height / 4);
                    console.log(_this.x);

                    };
                };
            };
        };
```

// For example I create two rows and set them different coordinates. I want them to be on the different sides if canvas;
        var first = new Row(0, 0);
        var second = new Row(350, 0);

```
   function init(){

        loadImage(imgArray);

        // IMG is the arrays with images links
        // New instances takes the different coordinates, but the last is overwriting the previous. Why?

        first.drawImage(IMG);
        second.drawImage(IMG);


    };
```

Comment: Probably `scope` issue, you have to put your details about how you create `canvas` and how you get that `ctx`, it seems you declare it globally.

Comment: I've already added.  But there is nothing special. Maybe the problem in the Row constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `first.drawImage`, this sets the `img.onload` handler. When you call `second.drawImage`, this OVERWRITES the `img.onload` handler. Try using `img.addEventListener('load', ...)` instead so that both callbacks are invoked.

Comment: Wow! Thanks you very very much! I've checked everywhere in my constructor, but even didn't thought that the problem could be in the onload function.